# "clickAt" not working in Eclipse using Selenium

Tags: selenium-ide, eclipse

I'm having a problem with my continuous integration, using Selenium IDE I can use `clickAt`, but while trying to build the "program" in eclipse I always get the error saying that `clickAt` is an "Unsupported command", what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

> I always get the error saying that clickAt is an "Unsupported command"

You will get this when converting Selenium IDE code to any language. It simply means that the webdriver version you are using doesn't have a 1-to-1 functionality match with the IDE options.

> what should I do ?

Use [actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html). See [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8536/11015) SO answer for an example.

Comment: thank you @kirbycope but still it didnt work...i'm a begginer! i need to make a while loop that will be clicking on some specific places located by id. any idea ?

Comment: What you were trying was by pixel position. Using Selenium selectors is really simple if you have ID's. Do a quick Google search, there are tons of blogs and such that cover selectors.