# How to use OCR in Selenium to identify dynamic objects

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to implement [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) ([tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/), [Abbyy](https://www.abbyy.com/), [MODI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10130/OCR-with-Microsoft-Office), [Aprise](https://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html), etc..) to identify **dynamically** changing web elements in application page at automation runtime. This way the Selenium webdriver automation script will always work without ever changing the object locators in the code.

Any directions to get started?

Comment: what is OCR/OR?

Comment: So, what's the problem? Take a screenshot and run your ocr of choice on it, maybe cut out the "suspicious" section and do some preparation since at least tesseract doesn't seem to like noise pictures too much (or I'm just bad with tesseract) and it should work. Had something like this running for language validation at some point, if you tell us what's your problem and if it fits I could look for it.

Comment: You mean you have objects that have a new name every time the page is loaded? Do you have an example? Probably there is a better way to find a locator that does not need constant updating.

Comment: I am looking to use OCR how same feature is avaibale in robotic  process automation tools like UIPath, Automation Anywhere to perform action on objects during runtime for dynamic changing objects on page .

Comment: Object locator will not work always in dynamic object change . for ex- if element is avable inside a web table and the table locator is changing constantly or its in div (each time div updates id or class with different text format which is not follow  in any pattern) in that case its very difficult to manage. Only can be updated once it got failed after test run.

Answer (score 2):

The flow for something like that would look something like this:

1. Take a [screenshot of your full browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)
2. Analyse the screenshot with your OCR software and [let it return coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041038/is-there-an-ocr-library-that-outputs-coordinates-of-words-found-within-an-image)
3. Interact with the element on that location, e.g. [click item coordinates](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/selenium-how-to-click-at-x-y-coordinates).

You say you want this because:

> The Selenium script will always work without changing object locators in code

I think your thought process is interesting, but I think this is a dream and a lie. What if the application changes so that your OCR software finds two or more objects with the same text? Which one should it use? What if you have multiple elements that look the same, but the order has changed. Think about edit buttons. I think you will introduce new maintainability issues, while you increase the complexity of the testing framework hugely.

I assume you want to solve maintainability issues of Selenium tests, I would try:

- Learn to write [good Selenium locators](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator)
- Centralize actions and locators in [Page Objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html)
- Force developers to run and update test during development, not afterwards by testers. I would also let the developers create the happy-path tests and extend those by testers if needed.
- Write less Selenium tests, follow the guideline [test automation effort spread](https://medium.com/@NReijmersdal/the-test-eiffeltower-versus-test-pyramids-3b15e8621122#37cb) as described by the [test-pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html).

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have ruled working on the DOM level with selectors.

So if you want to do **visual testing**, I see several options:

1. If you are not tied to Selenium, use the free [Kantu web testing](https://a9t9.com/kantu/web-testing)
   tool, which works *visually*, just the way you want it to work. It
   has built-in [OCR](https://a9t9.com/kantu/docs/scraping#ocr). At the very least, you can use this tool test
   if the visual testing approach itself is the right one for your test
   case - before spending much time to get Selenium to work this way.

**If Selenium:**

2. OCR for use with Selenium: Go for an [online ocr solution](https://ocr.space/compare-ocr-software), it
   will be much easier to use than implementing Tesseract. Here is some
   [Java code](https://ocr.space/ocrapi#java) to use it.
3. Maybe you do not need OCR, but "only" image recognition? In this
   case [Selenium + Sikuli](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/integration-of-sikuli-with-selenium-webdriver/) is an option.